# Get projects filtered by categories in Active Collab

Tags: php, api, activecollab

I'm using the feather API to retrieve projects and categories.

I was wondering if it is possible to get projects tagged to a specific category?

E.g.

```
$client->get('projects?category_id=15')->getJson()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what did you try? please give some more info. do you have error messages?

Comment: Hi @swe - I tired a lot of different ways. Sorry for the brief question but this is the only place Active Collab answer any API questions. In the end I just got the projects and then looped through

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, unfortunately.